# I get a significant difference in my accuracy when testing a saved model in my current module or an external module

Tags: python, tensorflow

train.py

```
y = cnn_model.CNN(x)
...
print("Optimization Finished!")
tf.reset_default_graph()
saver.restore(sess, MODEL_DIRECTORY)

# Calculate accuracy for all mnist test images
test_size = test_labels.shape[0]
batch_size = 50
total_batch = int(test_size / batch_size)

acc_buffer = []

# Loop over all batches
for i in range(total_batch):
    # Compute the offset of the current minibatch in the data.
    offset = (i * batch_size) % (test_size)
    batch_xs = test_data[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_ys = test_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    y_final = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, is_training: False})
    correct_prediction = numpy.equal(numpy.argmax(y_final, 1), numpy.argmax(batch_ys, 1))
    acc_buffer.append(numpy.sum(correct_prediction) / batch_size)

print("******Test Results **********")
print("test accuracy for the current model: %g" % numpy.mean(acc_buffer))
```

> > test accuracy for the current model:0.9756

```
sess.close()
tf.reset_default_graph()
test.test_org(MODEL_DIRECTORY, batch_size)
```

test.py

```
def test_org(model_directory, batch_size):
train_total_data, train_size, validation_data, validation_labels, test_data, 
    test_labels = mnist_data.prepare_MNIST_data(
    False)

is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='MODE')

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])  # answer
y = cnn_model.CNN(x, is_training=is_training)

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={is_training: True})

# Restore variables from disk
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Calculate accuracy for all mnist test images
test_size = test_labels.shape[0]
print(test_size)
total_batch = int(test_size / batch_size)

saver.restore(sess, model_directory)

acc_buffer = []

# Loop over all batches
for i in range(total_batch):
    # Compute the offset of the current minibatch in the data.
    offset = (i * batch_size) % (test_size)
    batch_xs = test_data[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_ys = test_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    y_final = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, is_training: False})
    correct_prediction = numpy.equal(numpy.argmax(y_final, 1), numpy.argmax(batch_ys, 1))
    acc_buffer.append(numpy.sum(correct_prediction) / batch_size)
print("******Test Results **********")
print("test accuracy for the stored model: %g" % numpy.mean(acc_buffer))
```

> > test accuracy for the stored model: .9838

It appears that the steps to calculate accuracy are identical but I can't understand why the values are different. In the train.py, I just finished training my model, should I not use the same session when I'm restoring?

Found the issue. In my train.py, I didn't pass in the is_training variable when initializing my model. But in my test.py, I do pass in the variable.

y = cnn_model.CNN(x, is_training=is_training)

So when I run my accuracy check in train.py, the is_training=false has no affect causing the results to be slightly off.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving after you train? I don't tensorflow, but it looks like the only thing related to saving is at the beginning of your train.py

Comment: @Bailey Thx for the comment, as I rechecked my code, I spotted the issue with initializing my model.